# Vertically aligning floated label in the middle of an input element Ionic

Tags: css, ionic2, position, label, vertical-alignment

So, I don't want to use placeholder, instead I want to use ion-label like placeholder. I need to vertically align **FLOATED** ion-label inside an ion-input element and when user clicks and/or enter the text in ion-input field ion-label should stay on top of it.

This is what I got so far:

IONIC:

```
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating class="label__placeholder">SMS</ion-label>
      <ion-input name="first_name"
        type="text"
        ngModel
        required>
      </ion-input>
    </ion-item>
```

SCSS:

```
    ion-label {
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      font-size: 18px !important;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      padding-left: 15px;

      &.label__placeholder {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 30px;
      }
    }
```

This is the picture how it is now and how ion-label should look like when it's not clicked on ion-input:

[image]

And this is when I click on ion-input, ion-label goes on top of ion-input but it's not visible:

[image]

And this is how it should look like when ion-input is clicked:

[image]

I managed to position ion-label in the middle of an ion-input but when I click on ion-input, ion-label goes on top of the ion-input and it's not visible, like it goes somewhere behind, don't know where. Tried to use z-index also but it didn't help.

Comment: what does css class "label__placeholder" doing?

Comment: @PrerakTiwari It positions label in the middle of an ion-input. I provided scss styles for it, just edited to make it more noticeable

Comment: try removing position:absolute, it should work then.

Comment: @PrerakTiwari I removed position: absolute as you suggested and now the label is visible when it goes on top of ion-input but when it's in it (when it's not clicked on ion-input) it's not aligned vertically in the middle of an ion-input and it should be. Any suggest how to solve that part?

Comment: can you post the image how its looking right now and how you wanted?

Comment: @PrerakTiwari O.K. I updated my question so you can see now. The first picture is how I need ion-label to look like when ion-input is not clicked and the third picture is how it should look like when ion-input is clicked.
Here is the picture of what I got now with your code: 
http://imgur.com/zK1RgWo
You can see that ion-label is not vertically in the middle of ion-input, we need to make it go there :)

Comment: You can try removing bottom or margin-bottom to achieve I think. If it doesn't work then can you replicate it into plunker and then paste the link here, then I will take a look into your code

Comment: @PrerakTiwari solved this today. Posted solution as answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem. I removed position: absolute and bottom: 30px from &.label__placeholder and use this code instead and it works:

```
    ion-label {
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      font-size: 18px !important;
      padding-left: 15px;
      &.label__placeholder {
        font-size: 15px !important;
        line-height: 13px;
        margin-bottom: 0 !important;
      }
    }
```

Here is how it looks now when ion-input is not clicked and when it is:
[image]

[image]